# How to use SSL in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ssl, ssl-certificate

I want to use SSL in my ASP.NET application. What should i do? I found many tutorials on the internet, but all of them, unfortunately, does not work (until then I had never worked with certificates).

What is the easiest way to use SSL in ASP.NET applications? I am talking about self-signed certificates, of course.

Answer (score 7):

You can configure SSL with self signed certifcates in IIS with this tutorial

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/04/06/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates.aspx